# Creating Hash Values with variable Functions

Tags: encryption, hash

I am curious if it is possible to create a HASH value from an MD5 or SHA algorithm, such that if an attacker had a populated HASH table, and access to my HASH values, they wouldn't be able to guess the original value.  By this I mean that if someone populates a TABLE using MD5 or SHA algorithms on dictionary words, can I possibly run or generate a HASH with a variable parameter so that an attacker can't use use a pre-populated HASH table as they would have to guess the variable used to generate the HASH differently.

For instance:

Generate MD5 "OriginalText1" ---> FD823lF8lGSLJlDFDF....

Generate MD5 -variance 10000 "OriginalText1" ---> SLJDFLDSKJ3243243D....

I am not asking for a platform specific answer, but if you happen to provide one for Linux or Python, I would appreciate it.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check out [salting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))

Short explanation:
You store an additional random string and concatenate your "OriginalText1" with it -> "OriginalText1RANDOM". Then your hash function gets the concatenated version as input.

Advantage:

- Makes use of Rainbow Table close to impossible

Disadvantage:

- You need to store more data

Comment: Is there no way to create a MD5 or SHA (any HASH algorithm for that matter) value by running a command specifying it shouldn't use default parameters?  seems like it would be an advantage as one would only need to know that value, and the HASH wouldn't be guessable using Rainbow Tables.